# Android sprite animation with BitmapRegionDecoder

Tags: android, sprite

I'd like to animate a sprite.
I select the current frame by BitmapRegionDecoder, but it causes native crash on some Anroid 6.0 devices (mainly on Samsung).
I get this stack trace:

> ---
>
> Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zeroltexx/zerolte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G925FXXU4DPGW:user/release-keys'
>   Revision: '10'
>   ABI: 'arm64'
>   pid: 10872, tid: 10872, name: .aff.index.main  >>> com.aff.index.main <<<
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x30
>       x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000000000000002  x3   0000000000000000
>       x4   0000000000000000  x5   00000000ffffffff  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
>       x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000000
>       x12  0000007f1d0fd5c8  x13  0000000000000002  x14  0000000000000000  x15  000000c8000000c5
>       x16  0000007f7931c5f8  x17  0000007f7925e3dc  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000000000000000
>       x20  0000007f7563d180  x21  0000000000000001  x22  0000000000000000  x23  0000000000000000
>       x24  0000000000000000  x25  0000000000000000  x26  00000000ffffffff  x27  0000000000000000
>       x28  0000000000000000  x29  0000007fead6d070  x30  0000007f79264348
>       sp   0000007fead6d050  pc   0000007f7925e3dc  pstate 
>   backtrace:
>       #00 pc 00000000000f23dc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZNK7android6Bitmap4infoEv)
>       #01 pc 00000000000f8344  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN11GraphicsJNI12createBitmapEP7_JNIEnvPN7android6BitmapEiP11_jbyteArrayP8_jobjecti+60)
>       #02 pc 0000000000104224  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
>       #03 pc 0000000003f6b77c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x2f37000)

I call this runnable inside a View

```
   @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    try {
        if (isInited && region != null) canvas.drawBitmap(region, 0, 0, paint);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Timber.w(t, null);
    }
}

class AnimatePlaceholderRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 10) return;
            if (!isAnimating) return;
            if ((top + height + empty) <= maxTop) top = top + height + empty;
            else
                top = 0;
            bottom = top + height;
            src = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
            region = decoder.decodeRegion(src, null);
            invalidate();
            postDelayed(placeholderRunnable, 41);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Timber.w(t, null);
        }
    }
}
```

On many devices it runs well, e.g. on Nexus 6.0 with Android 7.0 or on a Sony XPeria Z1 with Android 5.x, but on my Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 6.x my app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once. The issue was that I was using a library that didn't bundle 64-bit arm code. Android has a bug where it assumes that if one library bundles 64-bit native code, that it assumes all libraries that use native code has 64-bit code in there. I believe Galaxy S7 is a 64bit phone. Check your exploded apk to see if this is the case.

You can load the entire sprint and crop regions from it using Java code.
You can find the answer on how to do that in this article.
[Android Devs, make your Toolbar and View backgrounds frosty](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/the-blurry-frosted-background-is-a-common-pattern-on-ios-where-they-have-simply-controls-to-cbd0c5843e5f)

In short:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
//half the size of the cropped bitmap
//to increase performance, it will also
//increase the blur effect.
matrix.setScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(spriteBitmap,
    (int) targetView.getX(), //start x
    (int) targetView.getY(), //start y
    targetView.getMeasuredWidth(), //end x
    targetView.getMeasureHeight(), //end y
    matrix,
    true);
```

My recommendation is to fall back on this if the first method didn't work.